# Object of type doesn't match target type 'Xamarin.Forms.ContentView'

Tags: xaml, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using portable Xamarin forms project. I get this error when I debug my page

[image]

xaml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   x:Class="Project1.Views.WebView1">

  <ContentView.Content>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

xaml.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Proje1.Views
{
    public partial class WebView1 : ContentPage
    {
        public WebView1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Label header = new Label
            {
                Text = "WebView",
                FontSize = 20,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            WebView wView = new WebView
            {
                Source = new UrlWebViewSource
                {
                    Url = "https://www.acikakademi.com",
                },
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
            this.Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    header,
                    wView
                }
            };
        }        
    }
}
```

What should I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set you `ContentPage` to a `ContentView`, so in your XAML set it to this: `<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" ...`

And in your code-behind do this: `public partial class WebView1 : ContentView`

[Also check out](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17469/contentview-and-contentpage) this thread on the Xamarin Forums on more of the differences. Which basically comes down to this:

> `ContentView` and `ContentPage` are meant to be used as base class for
>   your own views and pages. Use `ContentPage` when you want a `Page`, use
>   `ContentView` when you want a `View`

After closer examination of your XAML code notice how you've mixed the `ContentPage` and `ContentView`.

You root object declares a `ContentPage`, like so:

`<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"...`

But your Content says its a `ContentView`:

```
<ContentView.Content>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Change it to be consistent, so make it a page to use is as one, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   x:Class="Project1.Views.WebView1">

  <ContentPage.Content>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

It should now work.

Comment: But when I make it to inherit from ContentView, I get error in App.cs. How should I set the initial page in App.cs?

Comment: What error do you get then? And how are you trying to display your page?

Comment: Hello I have asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724234/cannot-implicily-convert-type-to-xamarin-forms-page

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   x:Class="Project1.Views.WebView1">

  <ContentView.Content>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

to

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   x:Class="Project1.Views.WebView1">

  <ContentPage.Content>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In your case, there is a mismatch between the property you're trying to set (`ContentView.Content` which means the property `Content` on the type `contentView`) and the View's type `ContentPage`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not need the Xaml at all as you define your view in code:

```cs
...
Label header = new Label
{
  Text = "WebView",
  FontSize = 20,
  FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};
WebView wView = new WebView
{
  Source = new UrlWebViewSource
  {
      Url = "https://www.acikakademi.com",
  },
  VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
};
this.Content = new StackLayout
{
  Children =
  {
    header,
    wView
  }
};
...
```

So you can delete the `.xaml` file, keep the `.xaml.cs` one but eventually rename it to `.cs` (not required, but nice), and remove the `InitializeComponent()` from your constructor:

```cs
public WebView1()
{
    Label header = new Label
    {
        ...
    };
...
```