# Cannot implicily convert type to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project, I have updated Xamarin and this is the new App.cs

```cs
public App()
{
    // The root page of your application
    var content = new ContentPage
    {
        Title = "Proje1",
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children = {
                new Label {
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                    }
                }
         }
    };

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
}
```

I get this error

> Cannot implicily convert type 'Proje1.Views.View1' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'

when I make this

```cs
MainPage = new View1();
```

I was pointing like this before, now how should I set the initial page in App.cs?

Comment: what is "View1" - that is not anywhere in your sample code?

Comment: I had been renamed in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `View1` inherit from `ContentView` somehow, so what you need is embed that in a `Page` so it's fit to be used as `Application.MainPage`.

```cs
MainPage = new ContentPage {
  Content = new View1()
};
```